# Gmail API messages list odd behaviour

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

So I've recently been working on a server-side application which collects [message lists](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) from users, based on history id. I am doing full syncs.

Normally, I get responses like this:

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "14d9c91dbba84646",
   "threadId": "14d9a7f9b36c65ae"
  }, 
],
 "nextPageToken": "14788016228466612591",
 "resultSizeEstimate": 832
}
```

which is precisely what I get in 99% of cases. However, for some users, I get only this:

```
{"resultSizeEstimate":0}
```

with no other information. Note that this is on a full sync. I find this odd, because even on brand new email accounts, I receive the oldest information. One of the emails providing this result is an @yahoo.com email. Which in itself is not so odd, since non-gmail accounts can have OAuth credentials. However, normally when a user has no gmail inbox I instead get a 400 error with failedPrecondition. Can anybody provide some insight on this behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by "a full sync"?  In my experience the margin of error on the resultSizeEstimate can be quite broad; like not even remotely in the ballpark. It can improve after using the nextPageToken a few times.  What exactly is your question?  Are you trying to claim that the estimate of zero is invalid?  How accurate does an estimate have to be to not be `wrong`?

Comment: What I mean by full sync is documented here: 

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync

I'm not trying to claim the estimate is invalid, I'm just wondering what the state of that mailbox is and What I should do with these users.It just strikes me as odd since I'm able to auth, but its an @yahoo.com email account

Comment: What makes you think they're a yahoo account? What they tell you their email address is, and the email address that they actually use to authenticate with can be two different things. Check what google thinks their email address is, eg: [getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile)

Comment: It is indeed a yahoo account as per the profile API. It also gives me a history ID. However, trying to pull a histories list based no that ID simply 404s.

Comment: Well that's interesting! Couple of theories: it's something new that gmail are working on to assist [their android app's new access to yahoo and outlook](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/20/check-out-gmail-5-0-for-android-and-googles-plan-to-handle-all-your-email-accounts-in-one-app/)-by building it into the gmailapi?  Or, less exciting, the user has setup an imap/pop pull from their yahoo account and somehow you're looking at their default alias/return address?  If you discover more on this keep me posted.

Comment: Yeah I'm gonna try to get in touch with the user I think. I'll report here if I find anything!

Comment: Getting back to the initial point: does anyone know why resultSizeEstimate gives odd numbers ?